# Word for anyone who forgets about anything in middle of a conversation

Tags: adjectives, single-word-requests

I've a friend who forgets about the topic on which we're having conversation at first place and deviates and talks about something else & then after sometime; in between he realizes that he is talking/discussing about different thing (which may or may not linked directly/indirectly with the original topic) and then we laughed about it.

But I'm just wondering if there's any specific word in English litrature about this thing.

Answer (score 1):

**wandering**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/wandering)

**to wander**

> 5. To turn the attention from one subject to another with little clarity or coherence of thought.

As in:

> I had a point to make, but my mind started wandering.

Answer (score 0):

You should say he has a *short attention span*

Via Macmillan Dictionary

> **Attention span**
>
> 1. the length of time that you can pay attention to one thing without becoming bored or thinking about something else

or that he is easily *sidetracked*

From Collins Dictionary:

> **Sidetrack**
>
> 1. to distract or be distracted from a main subject or topic

Answer (score 0):

How about "scatterbrained"?

[scatterbrain](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/scatterbrain):

> a person who forgets things easily or does not think seriously about
>   things

Answer (score 0):

The noun 'desultor' is rare and retains only its original meaning in English: *a rider trained to leap from one horse to another (as in the circensian games)* (M-W; qv).

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/desultory) has for the adjective, which OP's '[a] ... word ... about this thing' licenses,

**desultory**

> A desultory conversation leaps from one topic to another and doesn't
>   have a distinct point or direction.
>
> A desultory student skips from one
>   subject to another without applying serious effort to any one.
>
> A desultory comment is a digressive one that jumps away from the topic
>   at hand.
>
> And a desultory performance is one resulting from an implied
>   lack of steady, focused effort.

So both the friend and the conversation / conversational style may be termed 'desultory'.